# Devise RSpec Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I am trying to validate that the current_user's organization matches that of the organization they are trying to view.

Here's the part of the controller that's failing this test (@organization is being defined in an earlier method):

```
if current_user.organization != @organization
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this organization"
end
```

Here's the failing test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Admin::PagesController, :type => :controller do
  describe 'GET #home' do
    login_user

    before do
      @organization = FactoryGirl.create(:organization)
    end

    context "valid params" do
      it "renders the home template and returns http 200" do
      get :home, name: @organization.name
      expect(response).to render_template("home")
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my factory:

```
factory :user do
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  organization_id 1
  password "foobarfoobar"
  password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
end
```

...And here's where login_user is being defined:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in user
  end
end
```

Stacktrace:

```
  1) Admin::PagesController GET #home valid params renders the home template and returns http 200
 Failure/Error: it "renders the home template and returns http 200" do
   expecting <"home"> but rendering with <[]>
 # ./spec/controllers/admin/pages_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

However:

```
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AdminPagesController::GETHome::ValidParams>)> subject.current_user.organization == @organization
=> true
```

Not sure what is going wrong here, seems like pretty standard stuff. Any ideas?

Comment: whats the error? post the stacktrace please.

Comment: updated with stacktrace

Comment: When you create the organization in your before block, you have to attach the user to that organization. Like create the user with oraganization_id = @organization.id

Comment: It is already attached...? I have the user's organization_id equal 1 by default.

Comment: Also, your login_user method create a new user and then sign_in that user.
Somehow, you need to specify the relationship between organization and user

Comment: Please try my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I was sending in the wrong parameter - should have been sending `@organization.subdomain`, not `@organization.name`. :(

Comment: so its fixed now? glad that it fixed :)